# Set width of list items based on object values in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have an array with a set of objects inside.

```
var country_data = [
{"country_id":1,"country":"Luxembourg","local_wage":"407","wage":"489","exchange":"0.98"},
{"country_id":2,"country":"Norway","local_wage":"3200","wage":"378","exchange":"9.57"},
{"country_id":3,"country":"Austria","local_wage":"290","wage":"337","exchange":"0.87"},
{"country_id":4,"country":"United States","local_wage":"363","wage":"363","exchange":"1"},
{"country_id":5,"country":"United Kingdom","local_wage":"284","wage":"365","exchange":"0.68"}
];
```

I also have a for loop that retrieves the third value(wage) from each object:

```
for (var i=0; i<country_data.length; i++){
    var wage = country_data[i].wage;
    $('.countries.country_'+i).css('width', wage+'px');
```

I want to append to value of that figure to the width of the corresponding list element using the .css, width property.

```
<ul class="countries">
<li class="country_1">test</li>
<li class="country_2">test</li>
<li class="country_3">test</li>
<li class="country_4">test</li>
<li class="country_5">test</li>
</ul>
```

I can make it loop through the array but not append to the corresponding list elements. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, should be

```
$('.countries .country_' + i)
```

or

```
$('.country_' + i)
```

Also your `i` param is wrong. It strats with 0. You should use `country_data[i].country_id` instead most likely.